# Best practice for POST'ing to a new page with a redirect?

Tags: php, post, redirect, http-headers

I am trying to solve a workflow that looks something like this: (in PHP)

1. User enters order information in my shopping cart.
2. The order is captured and stored to my database (w/o credit card info)
3. The user is redirected to authorize.net's SIM page for payment

Current setup:

shoppingcart.php - collects user shipping information/etc

storeorder.php - stores the order in my database, and then assembles a form with the appropriate required authorize.net POST fields

In short, the user ends up having to view an unnecessary intermediate page where they have to click a "Make Payment" form submit button which then sends them to authorize.net.

What is the best practice for combining these steps?  (receiving a POST, storing info in my DB, and then auto-redirecting to authorize.net with new POST fields without any user interaction)

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT INTERFERE WITH USER's MONEY!
Even if you don't want store the credit card details, your site can be hacked and an attacker would get it.

1. User enters order information in my shopping cart.
2. The order is processed via authorize.net's SIM page for payment
3. authorize.net contact your site with payment details.

is the onlly proper way.
EVERY site in the world works this way. So you have to. Don't take yourself a smart ace.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user have to do any type of input on the authorize.net page or does your form supply all the needed information?  If you generate all the information then the easiest way to do it is via a cUrl call to authorize.net pushing the data directly to them and checking the return status code / output to see if it was a success / not etc.

If the user needs to still enter billing details use the following method.

Form posts to /somepage.php

somepage.php runs it's processing and all the way at the bottom once processing is completed add header("Location: https://www.authorize.net/dopaymenthere");

make sure you still echo the make payment button on this page, just in case the user does something wacky out of the ordinary where they force redirects to stop etc.  That way it doesn't look like broken code, but for the few exceptions that do out of the ordinary things to their browsers etc you can still handle them gracefully

PS: this would only work by concatenating the post variables as get requests, assuming that authorize.net would handle the get requests as variables.

The really easy way to do this without using a get request is with javascript by submitting the form on dom ready... that way you can show a processing order message to the user. and post them with an embedded hidden form directly to authorize.net in case your processing takes longer than expected etc.

In jquery terms on the processing.php page you would have something like:

```
echo $form; // HTML form with all it's values required by authorize.net
echo "<h1>Processing your request</h1>";
<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function(){$('#hiddenformid').submit();});</script>
```

Comment: ORIGINAL POSTER:  Yes, we are using the SIM method, so the user must enter all billing information on the authorize.net page.  (credit card #, expiration date, security code).  The reason we do not pass that information directly is because technically it puts you slightly out of PCI compliance.  (The user above is technically using the direct post method (DPM), not SIM).

Comment: The whole point of using a hosted form is to not have sensitive information running through your server.  If you're collecting payment data, then sending it to authorize.net, you might as well use AIM.

Comment: Based on your answer the easiest way to solve your problem is with an instant redirect that the user won't see.. I'll edit my anser to make it more clear...

Answer (score 0):

On `shoppingcart.php` you can place a button for Checkout. On pressing that the User action is submitted. `Do not save item prices/quantity in hidden fields.` on the POSTing of the user checkout button you can save all the info in your DB and make an HTML form in the PHP Post condition to set values for authorize.net and redirect your header to the PAYMENT page.